# Sharepoint 2013 additional default internal url via Alternate Access Mapping

Tags: sharepoint, default, internal

I have added a second default internal url via Alternate Access Mapping of my sharepoint 2013 server.
The reason for this is that instead of intranet.contoso.com want to access the same site just with typing intranet with preceeding http:// ofcourse. I also added the bindings in IIS but not working. I assumed that no extra dns entry is needed. Can someone tell how to manage this.

Thanks,

Comment: You might need a DNS change. Do you get the same IP when you ping intranet.contoso.com and intranet?

Comment: when I ping intranet get no reply back, although I have created a host A record in contoso.com zone. I am not sure whether a dns change is needed, i just added the entry to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot ping intranet but you can ping intranet.contoso.com you need to create a CNAME record that points intranet to intranet.contoso.com. The record needs to be created in the zone specified in the DNS Suffix Search List. Your DNS Suffix Search List can be found by running IPCONFIG /ALL from the command prompt.

References:

- http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/9847a59a-0200-45f2-8911-066eec38b97b/dns-question-adding-a-host-without-a-fqdn?forum=winservergen
- https://serverfault.com/questions/518079/how-do-i-set-up-dns-for-an-intranet-web-site
- http://www.mombu.com/microsoft/windows-server-dns/t-internal-host-without-fqdn-911196.html

Comment: thanks jrussellaz but even after adding CNAME I still cann't ping intranet, I only can ping it with FQDN. It is weird cause nowhere on internet to find an answer to this FAQ!!

Comment: See the updated information about the DNS Suffix Search List and the third link I refer to.

Comment: thanks the suggestion in the third link works but not when I use any other alias, e.g. intraweb instead of intranet.